# react native autocomplete list is empty

Tags: javascript, react-native

im newbie to React Native UI development
I am trying to develop a Searchable Dropdown FlatList Component, i came across
https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-searchable-dropdown &
https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-autocomplete-input

I found autocomplete input as more appropriate

I tried to implement it, but the list is emply.. please help me out what mistake or what exactly mistake i might be doing to implement it properly

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { DataList: [{
      id: 1,
      name: 'JavaScript',
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      name: 'Java',
    },
    {
      id: 3,
      name: 'Ruby',
    },
    {
      id: 4,
      name: 'React Native',
    },
    {
      id: 5,
      name: 'PHP',
    },
    {
      id: 6,
      name: 'Python',
    },
    {
      id: 7,
      name: 'Go',
    },
    {
      id: 8,
      name: 'Swift',
    },], query: '' };
  }

  findData(query) {
    if (query === '') {
      return [];
    }
    const { DataList } = this.state;
    const regex = new RegExp(`${query}`, 'i');
    return DataList .filter(data => data.name.search(regex) >= 0);
  }

...

render(){
    const { query } = this.state;
    const DataList = this.findData(query);

    const comp = (a, b) => a.toLowerCase().trim() === b.toLowerCase().trim();

    return (
...
<Autocomplete
          autoCapitalize="none"
          autoCorrect={false}
          containerStyle={styles.autocompleteContainer}
          data={DataList.length === 1 && comp(query, DataList[0].name) ? [] : DataList}
          defaultValue={query}
          onChangeText={text => this.setState({ query: text })}
          placeholder="Enter Name"
          renderItem={({ text }) => (
            <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this.setState({ query: text })}>
              <Text style={styles.itemText}>
                 {text}
              </Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
          )}
        />

...
)
```

Result Images [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/0IHRM.jpg [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/gtlHB.jpg
The [2] Image is what i want to develop at the end..

Thank you for your time and support :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The problem is with this code**

```
renderItem={({ text }) => (
            <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this.setState({ query: text })}>
              <Text style={styles.itemText}>
                 {text}
              </Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
          )}
```

**You will receive item in renderItem function not a text**

**Please change it to**

```
renderItem={({ item }) => (
            <TouchableOpacity
              onPress={() => this.setState({ query: item.name })}
            >
              <Text style={styles.itemText}>{item.name}</Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
          )}
```

**Sample App Demo**

[image]

**Complete Sample Code**

```
import React from "react";
import { View, Text, StyleSheet, TouchableOpacity } from "react-native";
import Autocomplete from "react-native-autocomplete-input";

export default class Home1 extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      DataList: [
        {
          id: 1,
          name: "JavaScript"
        },
        {
          id: 2,
          name: "Java"
        },
        {
          id: 3,
          name: "Ruby"
        },
        {
          id: 4,
          name: "React Native"
        },
        {
          id: 5,
          name: "PHP"
        },
        {
          id: 6,
          name: "Python"
        },
        {
          id: 7,
          name: "Go"
        },
        {
          id: 8,
          name: "Swift"
        }
      ],
      query: ""
    };
  }

  findData(query) {
    if (query === "") {
      return [];
    }
    const { DataList } = this.state;
    const regex = new RegExp(`${query}`, "i");
    return DataList.filter(data => data.name.search(regex) >= 0);
  }

  render() {
    const { query } = this.state;
    const DataList = this.findData(query);

    console.log("DataList", DataList);

    const comp = (a, b) => a.toLowerCase().trim() === b.toLowerCase().trim();

    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Autocomplete
          autoCapitalize="none"
          autoCorrect={false}
          containerStyle={styles.autocompleteContainer}
          data={
            DataList.length === 1 && comp(query, DataList[0].name)
              ? []
              : DataList
          }
          defaultValue={query}
          onChangeText={text => this.setState({ query: text })}
          placeholder="Enter Name"
          renderItem={({ item }) => (
            <TouchableOpacity
              onPress={() => this.setState({ query: item.name })}
            >
              <Text style={styles.itemText}>{item.name}</Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
          )}
        />
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    marginTop: 40
  },
  itemText: {
    padding: 16
  }
});
```

Comment: Amazing Sir <3 Thank you so much.
Today i came across [link](https://github.com/JedWatson/react-select)
Can i implement it in React-native.. 
i tried but throws me error saying 
TypeError: TypeError: null is not an object (evaluating 'cache.registered')

the above lib is such amazing.. which can solve and exactly appropriate component which i want to implement

Comment: @Ayush Agarwal Please mark correct and upvote if answer is helpful

Comment: done, please also look to the above comment. Thank you <3

Comment: The link you have given is for Web(React.js) . For React native you can try this library [react-native-searchable-dropdown](https://github.com/zubairpaizer/react-native-searchable-dropdown)

Comment: i have tried it, its working perfectly but the im not expert right now, i want to display the list in overlay or model, like a dropdown
this lib pushes the following others components down